# Calculating an array of values in C# (Formula convert from Excel)

Tags: c#, excel, multidimensional-array, lazy-evaluation, calculated-columns

I'm currently building a semi-complicated calculator which is basically a conversion from an Excel spreadsheet I've been provided.

I've nailed most of it but there's a part in the Excel spreadsheet where multiple calculations occur between 6 rows and 7 columns, but the issue is that the calculations happen in no particular order what-so-ever.

So for example, `Row0[Column1]` is calculated using `(Row2[Column4] * Row2[Column5])` and `Row1[Column4]` is calculated using `(Row4[Column2] / Row5[Column1])` and so forth.. you get the idea.

I've thought about using a 2D array, but am afraid that the values will calculate in a particular order, thus having no value when they are reached. As far as I'm aware, **Row1** will be calculated first, then **Row2**, **Row3**, etc.

So, without creating a variable for each cell in my excel spreadsheet (and ordering it appropriately), is there a way I can calculate this using C#?

I would really appreciate any help, advice, pointers, whatever you think may be possible - I'd love to hear it!

**EDIT** After implementing the Lazy class provided by **@dtb**, I've got the following code. It's a straight copy of what's in the Excel spreadsheet I've been provided, including pointers & calculations.

```
var sr = new Lazy<decimal>[6, 6];
sr[0, 0] = new Lazy<decimal>(() => sr[1, 0].Value - eNumber);
sr[0, 3] = new Lazy<decimal>(() => sr[0, 4].Value - sr[1, 0].Value - sr[1, 4].Value);
sr[0, 4] = new Lazy<decimal>(() => sr[0, 0].Value * edD);
sr[0, 5] = new Lazy<decimal>(() => sr[0, 0].Value);

sr[1, 0] = new Lazy<decimal>(() => sr[1, 5].Value);
sr[1, 4] = new Lazy<decimal>(() => sr[1, 0].Value * edD);
sr[1, 5] = new Lazy<decimal>(() => sr[2, 0].Value + sr[2, 5].Value);

sr[2, 0] = new Lazy<decimal>(() => eNumber * rRate);
sr[2, 4] = new Lazy<decimal>(() => sr[2, 0].Value * hdD);
sr[2, 5] = new Lazy<decimal>(() => sr[1, 5].Value);

sr[3, 1] = new Lazy<decimal>(() => sr[2, 5].Value);

sr[4, 2] = new Lazy<decimal>(() => eNumber * (ePc / 100) + sr[2, 0].Value * (hlPc / 100) - sr[3, 1].Value);

sr[5, 0] = new Lazy<decimal>(() => (sr[0, 0].Value + sr[1, 0].Value + sr[2, 0].Value) / ePerR);
sr[5, 2] = new Lazy<decimal>(() => sr[5, 0].Value / rLifecycle);
sr[5, 4] = new Lazy<decimal>(() => sr[5, 2].Value);
sr[5, 5] = new Lazy<decimal>(() => sr[5, 0].Value + sr[5, 2].Value - sr[5, 4].Value);
```

**However I get the following error**
`ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.`

Googling the error has returned a bunch of spammy search type websites.

Marko

Comment: What kind of error is it? A compiler error or an exception? Did you enhance the Lazy class to do circular dependency detection by any chance? Because there's one in your definitions: sr[1,5] is defined in terms of sr[2,5] and vice versa.

Comment: Hi @dtb - the project compiles but I get an Exception. I've resorted to using .NET 4 for the time being (until I get it working in the original class). By the way, I'm not sure how to extend the class for Circular Dependencies, that's (quite) a bit outside my knowledge scope.

Comment: Then you've just encountered the circular dependency detection of the .NET 4.0 Lazy class. You can implement it yourself by setting valueCreated to 1 *before* calling valueFactory, to 2 after, and by throwing an exception if Value is called and valueCreated is 1... Double check if there's really a circular definition in your excel sheet. If there is, post a new question with the excel formulas and ask how to calculate the fix-point in C#. But I suspect you've got a typo in your code.

Comment: I've triple checked the code and that's exactly what's in the spreadsheet, so that means that I do need to implement the circular dependency? Shall I ask a new question about that?

Comment: If there is a circular dependency then my approach using Lazy does not work. Ask a new question with the exact set of excel formulas. Include the word "fixed point" and a link to this question. :-)

Comment: That is, do not ask how to extend the Lazy class to support circular dependencies. I believe your problem cannot be solved in a generic way. You need a solution specific to your set of formulas.

Comment: @dtb - Bummer. It did really look like a valid solution. I guess I'm gonna have to re-think the whole thing - or statically assign variables in the order they're being calculated. A 3rd option would be to try and clean up the circular references. Either way, I'm accepting your answer since your solution got pretty close.

Comment: @Marko Ivanovski: Your definitions are really weird. I have no idea how excel's calculating that. `sr[2,5] := sr[1,5]` and `sr[1,5] := sr[2,0] + sr[2,5]` and `sr[2,0]` is some constant. That doesn't look like it'd converge to some value at all. What values does excel show for `sr[2,5]` and `sr[1,5]`?

Comment: @dtb I know - it's a mix of too many cells and roundtrips - but that's what's in the Excel and works. I guess I could try and clean it up a bit before going any further with the conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at **Lazy Evaluation**:

```
var table = new Lazy<int>[2, 2];

table[0, 0] = new Lazy<int>(() => table[1, 1].Value * 2);
table[0, 1] = new Lazy<int>(() => 42);
table[1, 0] = new Lazy<int>(() => 100);
table[1, 1] = new Lazy<int>(() => table[0, 1].Value + table[1, 0].Value);

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Row = {0}  Column = {1}  Value = {2}",
                             i,            j,           table[i, j].Value);
}
```

Note how the content of the table cells are defined in arbitrary order. It figure out the order itself, as long as there are no circular dependencies between cells.

Output:

```
Row = 0  Column = 0  Value = 284
Row = 0  Column = 1  Value = 42
Row = 1  Column = 0  Value = 100
Row = 1  Column = 1  Value = 142
```

---

It becomes slightly more readable with **LINQ-to-Lazy**:

```
var table = new Lazy<int>[2, 2];

table[0, 0] = from t in table.AsLazy()
              from x in t[1, 1]
              select 2 * x;
table[0, 1] = 42.AsLazy();
table[1, 0] = 100.AsLazy();
table[1, 1] = from t in table.AsLazy()
              from a in t[0, 1]
              from b in t[1, 0]
              select a + b;
```

using

```
static class LazyExtensions
{
    public static Lazy<TResult> SelectMany<TSource, TCollection, TResult>(this Lazy<TSource> source, Func<TSource, Lazy<TCollection>> collectionSelector, Func<TSource, TCollection, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
        return new Lazy<TResult>(() => resultSelector(source.Value, collectionSelector(source.Value).Value));
    }

    public static Lazy<TSource> AsLazy<TSource>(this TSource value)
    {
        return new Lazy<TSource>(() => value);
    }
}
```

---

Custom replacement for .NET 4.0's [Lazy<T> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx):

```
sealed class MyLazy<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T> valueFactory;
    private T value;
    private bool valueCreated;

    public MyLazy(Func<T> valueFactory)
    {
        if (valueFactory == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("valueFactory");
        }
        this.valueFactory = valueFactory;
    }

    public bool IsValueCreated
    {
        get { return this.valueCreated; }
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (!this.valueCreated)
            {
                this.value = this.valueFactory();
                this.valueCreated = true;
            }
            return this.value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is Lazy a custom class? I'm using WPF (.NET 3.5) and Lazy doesn't exist.

Comment: [Lazy<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) is new in the .NET Framework 4.0. You should be able to build a custom  replacement pretty easily if you're stuck with 3.5.

Comment: Yeah I'm stuck with 3.5 on this one :( I'm trying now with the custom one you've provided.

Comment: Hi @dtb - I've implemented the solution - however I get an error *ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance*. Please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Marko, I think the best way is for you to map out the relationships between these cells.  If this question is about the order in which Excel would do it, I can point you to here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687891.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The lazy solution shown above is the most elegant, with one caveat which I'll mention below.

**Plan A**

You can code up your own version of `Lazy<T>` pretty easily (this is untested code):

```
class Lazy<T> {
  private bool IsEvaluated;
  private T Value;
  private Func<T> Suspension;
  public Lazy<T>(Func<T> susp) { Suspension = susp; }
  public static implicit operator T(Lazy<T> thunk) {
    if (thunk.IsEvaluated) {
      return thunk.Value;
    }
    thunk.Value = thunk.Suspension();
    thunk.IsEvaluated = true;
    return thunk.Value;
  }
}
```

Of course, you'll need to define overloaded arithmetic operators as well.

**Plan B**

Another way of tackling your problem is to sort your cells into increasing dependency order (where cell A depends on cell B if A contains a formula that uses B, directly or indirectly) and evaluate them in that order.

**Caveat**

If your dependencies contain a cycle then neither of these approaches is guaranteed to work since you will need to evaluate to a fixed point.  In that case you probably need something like Plan B, but first break your dependency graph into strongly connected components (there is a good answer on SCCs on this site).

Hope this helps.